# VisualStudio2015 Assembly program writing all strings at once?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, irvine32

I'm writing a program that will take an input, then convert it from one unit of length to another specified unit of length. The problem is my code is printing every string at once on the same line in my command prompt, and once you input your value and conversion, it just exits instead of displaying the value. Here's the code (I'm a newbie at ASM, prepare your eyes) :

```
include Irvine32.inc    

.data
len Dword ?
InL Dword ?
str5 Byte "Enter the value of your length"
str6 Byte "1 for Yards to feet, 2 for feet to inches, 3 for yards to inches"
str7 Byte "Your converted output is:"

.code
main proc
  lea edx, str5
   call WriteString
   call ReadDec ;prompts for a value and stores it as len
   mov len, eax
  lea edx, str6
   call WriteString
   call ReadDec
   mov InL, eax

   cmp InL, 2 ;prompts your conversion and compares it to send you to the right converter.
   jl YardsFeet
   je FeetInches
   jg YardsInches

YardsFeet:
 mov eax, 3
 MUL len
 jmp LenOut
FeetInches:
 mov eax, 12
 MUL len
 jmp LenOut
YardsInches:
 mov eax, 36
 Mul len
 jmp LenOut
LenOut:
mov eax, len
 lea edx, str7
 call WriteString
 Call WriteDec
 call crlf
exit
main endp
end main
```

I feel like it's probably something simple I'm overlooking but that's how most of these have gone for me lately.

Comment: "printing every string" in high level languages (like C), strings are implicitly terminated by a null character (\0).  Asm, being a low level language only uses the characters you explicitly indicate.  WriteString requires a null terminator.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd What does that mean? So far in class we haven't needed a null terminator as far as I remember. Do I just add \0 after the writestring?

Comment: It means use `label: Byte "hello", 0` to add a zero byte after the characters.

Comment: You're a lifesaver @PeterCordes

Comment: Adding "\0" at end of string (inside quotes) may work too (depends if MASM is capable to parse it same as C), in C it means the same thing as adding that zero as separate value, the final bytes produced should be same. Also when you create some string dynamically, writing zero after last character then works, but that means you need +1 size of buffer for creating null terminated strings, don't forget to plan ahead for the size of string + terminator.